# Softmax or sigmoid for multiclass problem

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, data-science

I am using VGG16 model and fine tuned them on my data. I am predicting ethnicity of images (faces) .i have 5 output classes like white, black,Asian, Sub-continent and others. Should i use softmax or sigmoid. And why??

Answer (score 1):

Sigmoid:

[image]

Softmax:

[image]

When you use a softmax, basically you get a probability of each class, (join distribution and a multinomial likelihood) **whose sum is bound to be one**.

In the case of softmax, increasing the output value of one class makes the others go down (because sum=1 always). If you plan to find exactly one value (which is the case in your ethnicity classifier) you should use softmax function. The character of this function is “there can be only one”. So these are ideally used in multi-class problems like your problem.

Things are different for the sigmoid function. This function can provide us with the top n results based on the threshold. The feature of the sigmoid is to emphasize multiple values (yes, can be more than one, hence called "multi-label"), based on the threshold, and we use it for the multi-label classification problems.

Answer (score 0):

In general cases, if you are dealing with multi-class clasification problems, you should use a **Softmax** because you are guaranted that the sum of probabilities of all clases will sum 1, by weighting them individually and computing the join distribution, whereas with a **Sigmoid**, you'd be predicting the probability of each class individually, but not necesarilly weighted. If not careful and aware of the difference you can run into some issues with your output.